# Draw word with negative letter spacing and boolean union

Tags: javascript, node.js, drawing

I need draw one word on SVG image with negative letter spacing and boolean union (Boolean operations on polygons, OR)
In result I need image like this

[image: negative letter spacing and union]

My app working on NodeJS. Which library can solve this problem?

Comment: Let us check what you already tried.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I'll deal with this in a few days

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 libraries for my task.

1. text-to-svg - draw each letter to svg
2. paper.js - make polygons (letters) union